# how to add variable error bars to scatter plot points with shared axes in python matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have generated a plot that shows a topographic profile with points along the profile that represent dated points. However, these dated points also have symmetric uncertainty values/error bars (that typically vary for each point).

In this example, I treat non-dated locations as 'np.nan'. I would like to add uncertainty values to the y2 axis (Mean Age) with defined uncertainty values as y2err.

Everytime I use the ax2.errorbar( ... ) line, my graph is squeezed and distorted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
#Longitude = x; Elevation = y
x = (-110.75696,-110.75668,-110.75640,-110.75612,-110.75584,-110.75556,-110.75528)
y = (877,879,878,873,871,872,872)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_xlabel('Longitude')
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('Elevation', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
# Mean Age, np.nan = 0.0
y2 = (np.nan,20,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan)
y2err = (np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan)
ax2.scatter(x, y2, color='r')
#add error bars to scatter plot points
# (??????) ax2.errorbar(x, y, y2, y2err, capsize = 0, color='black')
ax2.set_ylim(10,30)
ax2.set_ylabel('Mean Age', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If I do not apply the ax2.errorbar... line my plot looks like the first image, which is what I want but with the points showing uncertainty values (+/- equal on both side of point in the y-axis direction).
[Plot of Elevation vs Age without error bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9027.png)

When I use the ax2.errorbar line it looks like the second image:
[Plot when using ax2.errorbar line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWPCQ.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Your code `ax2.errorbar(x, y, y2, y2err, capsize = 0, color='black')` which provided 2 y-value seems incorrect and doesn't give any error bar as per my test. Remove `y, ` gives me what you are looking for. Do you mind trying that?

Comment: That worked. Thanks for your response @Y. Luo!